# Memcached ERROR : Broken pipe / Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, linux, memcached, ubuntu-16.04

When I am setting the **huge** data using Java MemcachedClient(`com.whalin.MemCached`), getting the `broken pipe` & `Connection reset by peer` errors.

Here is my configuration file. [`/etc/memcached.conf`]

```
# memcached default config file
# 2003 - Jay Bonci <jaybonci@debian.org>
# This configuration file is read by the start-memcached script provided as
# part of the Debian GNU/Linux distribution.

# Run memcached as a daemon. This command is implied, and is not needed for the
# daemon to run. See the README.Debian that comes with this package for more
# information.
-d

# Log memcached's output to /var/log/memcached
logfile /var/log/memcached.log

# Be verbose
 -v

# Be even more verbose (print client commands as well)
 -vv

# Start with a cap of 64 megs of memory. It's reasonable, and the daemon default
# Note that the daemon will grow to this size, but does not start out holding this much
# memory
-m 4096

# Default connection port is 11211
-p 11311

# Run the daemon as root. The start-memcached will default to running as root if no
# -u command is present in this config file
-u memcache

# Specify which IP address to listen on. The default is to listen on all IP addresses
# This parameter is one of the only security measures that memcached has, so make sure
# it's listening on a firewalled interface.
-l 127.0.0.1

# Limit the number of simultaneous incoming connections. The daemon default is 1024
# -c 1024

# Lock down all paged memory. Consult with the README and homepage before you do this
# -k

# Return error when memory is exhausted (rather than removing items)
# -M

# Maximize core file limit
# -r
```

Even after the size has been increased to 4096, still those errors are coming.

**One more Issue** : 
Not able to get the log file, even it is un-commented

Running process

```
memcache  9304     1  0 11:26 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/memcached -v -vv -m 4096 -p 11311 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1
```

**FYI** : Reading the 50000 records from DB, adding to the map and storing that map into the Memcache.

## Broken Pipe :

```
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
        at com.schooner.MemCached.SockOutputStream.writeToChannel(Unknown Source)
        at com.schooner.MemCached.SockOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1189)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
        at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1790)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor100.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1128)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
        at com.schooner.MemCached.ObjectTransCoder.encode(Unknown Source)
        at com.schooner.MemCached.AbstractTransCoder.encode(Unknown Source)
        at com.schooner.MemCached.AscIIClient.set(Unknown Source)
        at com.schooner.MemCached.AscIIClient.set(Unknown Source)
        at com.whalin.MemCached.MemCachedClient.set(Unknown Source)
```

## Connection reset by user

```
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
        at com.schooner.MemCached.SockOutputStream.writeToChannel(Unknown Source)
        at com.schooner.MemCached.SockOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1189)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
        at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1790)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor100.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1128)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
        at com.schooner.MemCached.ObjectTransCoder.encode(Unknown Source)
        at com.schooner.MemCached.AbstractTransCoder.encode(Unknown Source)
        at com.schooner.MemCached.AscIIClient.set(Unknown Source)
        at com.schooner.MemCached.AscIIClient.set(Unknown Source)
        at com.whalin.MemCached.MemCachedClient.set(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be that you are trying to store very large objects to memcache

By default memcache allows a max of 1MB objects to be set. in newer versions of memcache you can set the -I option to increase the size to a max of 128MB. (https://linux.die.net/man/1/memcached)

I would not recommend it though. Its better to create smaller objects.

Comment: Yes. The data we try to store is more. I tried `-I` option to set 128MB. Still it is failing. As we are storing the whole table data in a single key, If the table size is more then problem is coming. By the way as per my testing I am able to store 13K objects (each row has 5 columns) into a single key. After that this issue is coming. Thanks for the reply..

Comment: Why store the whole table in memcache. If you require the whole table then it would be better to fetch if from DB. In most of the cases it won't be needed. In such cases you can always store maybe each row separately in memcache for fast retrieval. if you need a few rows at a time, do a multiget.